# How do I use a PHP form?

Tags: php, forms, web, parameters

I have this php file on my Webserver which is supporting php.

$Content = $_POST['Content'];

echo $Content;

When I open the file, which is called put.php, put.php?Content=200 nothing happens.

Maybe anyone of you could help me. I have already read that it runs with a html file where the user fill der information and press a button to send it, but i only want to open the php file with specified information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because Content=200 is of the GET method. Not POST. Try $Content = $_GET['Content']; instead ;)

Comment: You are right. Thanks so far. What can I do that it is POST, I have read POST has a bigger capacity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, `$_POST` refers to variables that are set by **form submission**

`$_GET` is used to get query string parameters , i.e. `put.php?Content=200`;

```
echo $_GET['Content'];
```

Please note that directly echoing `$_GET` or `$_POST` can open your site to being used for XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the security evidence. Actually I'm just finding out, how to save PHP forms, i will later put the values in my database give back true or false and also you will need a ID to run the script. For the most Time I will use it in a mobile Application. But Thanks for the evidence :)!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a POST form. As Machavity told you, it's insecure to do it this way, but it'll teach you the basics. I've put comments inside that'll tell you what's doing exactly what.

```
<?php

/*
First we'll make an if statement that checks if there's actually
a username set. In here you'll see "isset". This checks if the POST
variable 'username' exists. Secondly you see "empty". This will
check if the variable is empty. Ofcourse we don't want it to be
empty, so we'll put a ! in front of it. This makes it do exact opposite
and check if it's NOT empty.
*/
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
    //Here we'll echo a message to the user with his username and
    //2 returns so the form is a little bit further down.
    echo "Hello, " . $_POST['username'] . "<br /><br />";
}

//With this we can even give the user a message when he tries to
//sumit the form without entering a username at all.
if(empty($_POST['username'])){
    echo "You did not enter a username! <br /><br />";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Please enter your username</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- With method set to post, we're telling the form that we're using POST and not GET -->
        <!-- You should save this file as "example.php" as we're telling it to send the form data -->
        <!-- towards example.php. -->
        <form method="post" action="example.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
            Please enter your username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```